# SQL Output contents of a table to string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains many rows of SQL commands that make up a single SQL statement (to which I am grateful for this answer, step 5 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914303/sql-syntax-to-pivot-multiple-tables))

I have followed the example in this answer and now have a table of SQL - each row is a line of SQL that build a query.  I can copy and paste the contents of this table into a new query window and get the results however due to my lack of SQL knowledge I am not sure how I go about copying the contents of the table into a string variable which I can then execute.

Edit: The SQL statement in my table comprises of 1 row per each line of the statement i.e.

```
Row1: SELECT * FROM myTable
Row2: WHERE
Row3: col = @value
```

This statement if copied into a VARCHAR(MAX) exceeds the MAX limit.

I look forward to your replies.  in the mean time I will try myself.

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use coalesce to concatenate the contents of a column into a string, e.g.

```
create table foo (sql varchar (max));

insert foo (sql) values ('select name from sys.objects')
insert foo (sql) values ('select name from sys.indexes')

declare @sql_output varchar (max)
set @sql_output = ''       -- NULL + '' = NULL, so we need to have a seed
select @sql_output =       -- string to avoid losing the first line.
       coalesce (@sql_output + sql + char (10), '')
  from foo

print @sql_output
```

Note: untested, just off the top of my head, but a working example of this should produce the following output:

```
select name from sys.objects
select name from sys.indexes
```

You can then execute the contents of the string with `exec (@sql_output)` or `sp_executesql`.

Comment: thats goodm, thanks.  The only problem I do have is that my table contains more statements than varchar(max) can handle.  Whats another suitable datatype I can use.  I am using SQL Server 2008 if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
        SqlString VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE (SqlString) SELECT 'SELECT 1'

DECLARE @SqlString VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  TOP 1 @SqlString = SqlString FROM @TABLE

EXEC (@SqlString)
```

Concatenate string from multiple rows

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Val VARCHAR(50)
)
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val) SELECT 1, 'SELECT *'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val) SELECT 2, 'FROM YourTable'
INSERT INTO @Table (ID,Val) SELECT 3, 'WHERE 1 = 1'

DECLARE @SqlString VARCHAR(MAX)
--Concat
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        @SqlString =
        (
            SELECT  tIn.Val + ' '
            FROM    @Table tIn
            ORDER BY ID
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
FROM    @Table t

PRINT @SqlString
```

Comment: the table I am converting into a string is larger than VARCHAR(MAX)? Can you recommend a suitable datatype.  The table contains around 400 rows.  Thanks, this is almost what I am looking for.

Comment: Have a look here teratrax.com/articles/varchar_max.html. It states *These data types can hold the same amount of data BLOBs can hold (2 GB)*

Comment: interesting, my sql query definitely does not pass 2GB!!  I am using VARCHAR(MAX) as per your declare above.

Comment: Are you looking to concatenate the sql strings from the table before you execute it, or execute all of the entries one at a time? What seems to be the issue?

Comment: The table contains about 300 rows each containing a line from a single SQL query (I edited my question to reflect this now, hope this makes it clearer).  Using a combination of your answer and the answer from concernedoftunbridgewells above I attempt to "EXEC @sqlString" but I get an error so I looked at the string using "print @sqlstring" and I can only see the first 16 rows from the table which is why I am getting the error.  This is why I thought the @SqlString was maxed out! Obviously not

Comment: Well then you would want to concatenate the string before you exec it.

Comment: I found the issue.  I used EXEC @sqlstring instead of EXEC (@sqlstring).  This made all the difference.

Comment: I thank you for your help as it pointed me in the right direction.  Not sure why this would make the difference though.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute a string of sql then use [Exec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)() or [sp_executeSql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)