# Sql Syntax: Update All values in table based on a value in a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables and I want to update all values for a particular type to the same value:

table1:
id, ValueType

table2:
id, Value

table3:
id, fkValueTypeId, fkValueId

fkValueType references ID in table1. fkValue references ID in Table2

I am trying to set all Speed values to the same value:

i.e.

```
Table1:
0, speed
1, age
2, colour

Table2:
0, 10
1, 20
2, 30
3, 40
4, 18
5, 18
6, blue
7, black
8, orange
9, 33
10, 34
11, 35

Table3:
0, 0, 0      --Speed = 10
1, 0, 0      --Speed = 20
2, 0, 0      --Speed = 30
3, 0, 0      --Speed = 40
4, 1, 1      --Age = 18
5, 1, 1      --Age = 18
6, 2, 2      --Colour = Blue
7, 2, 2      --Colour = Black
8, 2, 2      --Colour = Orange
9, 0, 9      --Speed = 33
10, 0, 10    --Speed = 34
11, 0, 11    --Speed = 35
```

What I want to do is Update Speed to '55' for all Speed entries in the tables so that table2 looks like this:

```
Table2:
0, 55
1, 55
2, 55
3, 55
4, 18
5, 18
6, blue
7, black
8, orange
9, 55
10, 55
11, 55
```

Hope this makes sense.  I am not sure on the syntax and can do it using a loop but wondered if there is a better way (which I am sure there is!).

Thank you

Comment: sorry to digress a bit, but this looks like an EAV pattern. Shouldn't the table be like this
ID Color Speed age ?

You might run into serious performance issues later on.

Comment: its based on the answer from a previous question of mine and I want to update all measurements from the measurement table PropertyType.Name to a single value:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762305/sql-server-one-table-with-400-columns-or-40-tables-with-10-columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rewrite of @hobodave's answer:

```
UPDATE table2
SET Value = 55
FROM table2
JOIN table3 ON table3.fkValueId = table2.id
WHERE table3.fkValueTypeId = 0
```

Comment: I changed my syntax to match this and still have "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'".  Adding FROM Table2 just before the Join gets rid of the error but I am still trying to get this working.

Comment: ok, adding "FROM table2" before the JOIN makes this work.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table2
SET table2.Value = 55
FROM table2
JOIN table3 ON table3.fkValueId = table2.id
WHERE table3.fkValueTypeId = 0
```

Edit: wasn't aware of SQL server's syntax warts :)

Comment: Thats similar to what I was trying and I get the following error:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.

Comment: adding "FROM table2" before the JOIN makes this work.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I was winging it using standard SQL, wasn't aware of sql server's warts. :)