# Advice on optimizing speed for a Stored Procedure that uses Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, view

Based on a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762305/sql-server-one-table-with-400-columns-or-40-tables-with-10-columns) and with a lot of help from [Damir Sudarevic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196713/damir-sudarevic) (thanks) I have the following sql code which works great but is very slow.  Can anyone suggest how I can speed this up and optimise for speed.

I am now using SQL Server Express 2008 (not 2005 as per my original question).

What this code does is retrieves parameters and their associated values from several tables and rotates the table in a form that can be easily compared.  Its great for one of two rows of data but now I am testing with 100 rows and to run GetJobParameters takes over 7 minutes to complete?

Any advice is gratefully accepted, thank you in advanced.

```
/***********************************************************************************************
**  CREATE A VIEW (VIRTUAL TABLE) TO ALLOW EASIER RETREIVAL OF PARMETERS
************************************************************************************************/
CREATE VIEW dbo.vParameters AS 
SELECT  m.MachineID AS [Machine ID]
,j.JobID AS [Job ID]
,p.ParamID AS [Param ID]
,t.ParamTypeID AS [Param Type ID]
,m.Name AS [Machine Name]
,j.Name AS [Job Name]
,t.Name AS [Param Type Name]
,t.JobDataType AS [Job DataType]
,x.Value AS [Measurement Value]
,x.Unit AS [Unit]
,y.Value AS [JobDataType]
FROM dbo.Machines AS m
JOIN dbo.JobFiles AS j ON j.MachineID = m.MachineID
JOIN dbo.JobParams AS p ON p.JobFileID = j.JobID
JOIN dbo.JobParamType AS t ON t.ParamTypeID = p.ParamTypeID
LEFT JOIN dbo.JobMeasurement AS x ON x.ParamID = p.ParamID
LEFT JOIN dbo.JobTrait AS y ON y.ParamID = p.ParamID

GO

-- Step 2
CREATE VIEW dbo.vJobValues AS 
SELECT  [Job Name]
       ,[Param Type Name]
       ,COALESCE(cast([Measurement Value] AS varchar(50)), [JobDataType]) AS [Val]
FROM dbo.vParameters

GO

/***********************************************************************************************
**  GET JOB PARMETERS FROM THE VIEW JUST CREATED
************************************************************************************************/
CREATE PROCEDURE GetJobParameters
AS

-- Step 3

DECLARE @Params TABLE (
id int IDENTITY (1,1)
,ParamName varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @Params  (ParamName)
SELECT DISTINCT [Name]
FROM dbo.JobParamType

-- Step 4
DECLARE @qw TABLE(
id int IDENTITY (1,1)
, txt nchar(300)
)

INSERT  INTO @qw (txt)
  SELECT  'SELECT' UNION
  SELECT  '[Job Name]' ;

INSERT  INTO @qw (txt)   
  SELECT  ',MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN ''' + ParamName
  + ''' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [' + ParamName + ']'
  FROM  @Params
  ORDER BY id;

INSERT  INTO @qw (txt)
 SELECT  'FROM dbo.vJobValues' UNION
 SELECT  'GROUP BY [Job Name]' UNION
 SELECT  'ORDER BY [Job Name]';


-- Step 5
--SELECT txt FROM @qw

DECLARE @sql_output VARCHAR (MAX)
SET @sql_output = ''       -- NULL + '' = NULL, so we need to have a seed
SELECT @sql_output =       -- string to avoid losing the first line.
       COALESCE (@sql_output + txt + char (10), '')
  FROM @qw

EXEC (@sql_output)

GO
```

Output of @sql_output:

```
SELECT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
[Job Name]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '001' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [001]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '002' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [002]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '003' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [003]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '004' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [004]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '005' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [005]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '006' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [006]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '007' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [007]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '008' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [008]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '009' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [009]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '010' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [010]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '011' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [011]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '012' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [012]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '013' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [013]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '014' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [014]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '015' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [015]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN '016' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [016]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN 'Acceptance' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [Acceptance]                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN 'AdditionalOptionsAperture1' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [AdditionalOptionsAperture1]                                                                                                                                                                                       
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN 'AdditionalOptionsAperture2' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [AdditionalOptionsAperture2]                                                                                                                                                                                       
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN 'AdditionalOptionsBarcode' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [AdditionalOptionsBarcode]                                                                                                                                                                                           
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN 'AdditionalOptionsFiducial1' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [AdditionalOptionsFiducial1]                                                                                                                                                                                       
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN 'AdditionalOptionsFiducial2' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [AdditionalOptionsFiducial2]                                                                                                                                                                                       
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN 'AlignsFirstPcb' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [AlignsFirstPcb]                                                                                                                                                                                                               
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN 'Aperture1DefinedX' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [Aperture1DefinedX]                                                                                                                                                                                                         
,MAX(CASE [Param Type Name] WHEN 'Aperture1DefinedY' THEN Val ELSE NULL END) AS [Aperture1DefinedY]
```

and another 200 lines...

This is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Machines (
        MachineID   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
        PrinterType NVARCHAR(255), --UNIQUEIDENTIFIER REFERENCES PrinterTypes(TypeId),
        Name        NVARCHAR(255),
        [Desc]      NVARCHAR(MAX),
        HostName    NVARCHAR(255),
        IP          NVARCHAR(64), -- allows IPv4 and IPv6
        Serial      NVARCHAR(10),
        Location    NVARCHAR(255) )
GO  

    CREATE TABLE JobFiles (
        JobID       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
        MachineID   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER REFERENCES Machines(MachineID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        [Desc]      NVARCHAR(MAX),
        Name        NVARCHAR(255),
        JobOpen     BIT,
        [CreateDate]        DATETIME ,
        [ModifyDate]        DATETIME ,
        [CreatedByUser]     NVARCHAR(64)    ,
        [ModifiedByUser]    NVARCHAR(64)    )
GO  

    CREATE TABLE JobParamType (
        ParamTypeID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
        Name        NVARCHAR(255),
        [Desc]      NVARCHAR(MAX),
        JobDataType INT)

GO
    CREATE TABLE JobParamGroup (
        ParamGroupID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
        Name        NVARCHAR(255),
        [Desc]      NVARCHAR(MAX))

GO


    CREATE TABLE JobParams (
        ParamID     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
        ParamTypeID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER REFERENCES JobParamType(ParamTypeID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        ParamGroupID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER REFERENCES JobParamGroup(ParamGroupID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        JobFileID   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER REFERENCES JobFiles(JobID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        IsEnabled   BIT)

GO

    -- Text based property
    CREATE TABLE JobTrait (
        ParamID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES JobParams(ParamID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        Value       NVARCHAR(MAX) )
GO  

    -- Numeric based property   
    CREATE TABLE JobMeasurement (
        ParamID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES JobParams(ParamID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        Value   FLOAT,
        Format  NVARCHAR(20),
        Unit    NVARCHAR(MAX) )
```

Comment: Could you post what @sql_output contains? Have you looked at the execution plan?

Comment: I've added what SQL Studio Manager allows me to view when I run "Print @sql_output" instead of "EXEC (@sql_output)".

Comment: can you tell me what you mean by execution plan? I'm a sql newbie and on a steep learning curve... thank you.

Comment: In query analyzer, open the Query menu and check the *Include Actual Execution Plan*. Looking at your @sql_output though, I'm not surprised it takes a long time. I doubt any index will be able to speed this up but to be sure, take a good look at the plan and try to at least resolve every table scan by creating proper indexes.

Comment: Also, could you also post everything after the from clause? (no need to include another 200 columns but the from and where clause might provide some more insight).

Comment: take a look here http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/1968/any-way-around-the-print-limit-of-nvarcharmax-in-ssms for some solutions for your print problem.

Comment: thanks for your advice, adding indexes tot he foreign keys improved the speed (7m30s to just 2secs!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well without diving into the details of your database schema design, my first question would be have you created indexes on each of the join predicates used in your view definition?

In response to your comments.....

The typical starting point for a non performance tuned database is to:

1. Create a Clustered Index on each table, typically on the Primary key.
2. Create non clustered indexes on all foreign keys given that these will likely be used in T-SQL Join clauses.

Without a basic indexing strategy in place on your database the majority of your queries will perform table scans (i.e. every row in a table is touched), which is a bad thing.....

For an excellent and brief introduction to SQL Server Indexes, I suggest you read [Brad's Sure Guide to Indexes](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/brads-sure-guide-to-indexes/)

Comment: I have primary keys set but this is probably not enough. I have modified my question to include the schema and the output.

Comment: thank you, adding indexes to my foreign keys improved speed from 7 and half minutes to 2 seconds!!!  Excellent, thank you.

Comment: @Belliez: Also, don't forget to devise an index maintenance strategy to ensure optimal performance is provided from your indexes.