# SQL Table Row Convert to List of Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the best way to convert a row with columns to a list with rows?  In the list, I need one column with the old column name and one column with the old column value.

For Example:

Current:

PersonId | PersonFirstName | PersonLastName |

Need:

ColumnName | ColumnValue

Hope this makes sense.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx) clause. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples) question for some examples.

Comment: UNPIVOT works, but I'm getting this message (below) even though all my fields are varchar.

Comment: The type of column "" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: Can you please add query you have to the question?

Comment: SELECT Id, FieldName, FieldValue
FROM
(SELECT * FROM dbo.People WHERE Id = 1) p
UNPIVOT
(FieldValue FOR FieldName IN (Id, FirstName, LastName, DOB)) AS u
ORDER BY FieldName

Comment: @ArtOx, if the fields are different lengths, you will still get that type conflict error.  Try casting all of the fields to a common size.