# SQL Query that returns static values into rows instead of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like query like

```
SELECT 'FOO1', 'FOO2'
```

But returns the resultset into rows instead of columns

Comment: Could you expand on your question please. What data do you get back and what data did you expect to get back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT 'FOO1' as foo
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FOO2' as foo
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server: Examples of PIVOTing String data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)