# How to change data binding from left to right in Asp.net table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

Normally Table data bind from top to bottom with column headers at the top of the table.Is there way to change the data binding from left to right and headers in the first column of the table?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't automatically' do this is asp.net. You need to transform/pivot your data into the form you need. This is also called a crosstab report.

There are a few options:

1. DIY - Loop through the rows in your source data and manually transform it.
2. Do the pivot in SQL Server. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples) is a simple example on SO.
3. Use a 3rd-party pivot table control to do the hard work for you. eg [Devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) has fantastic asp.net [pivottable contro](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/ASP/Pivot_Grid/)l. There are other out there too. Unfortunately they are not free.

Comment: Thanks Geoff for pointing out about Pivot tables, found example from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Pivot.aspx)