# One row with 2 same name columns

Tags: sql

I wish to have a resultset with 2 columns of data coming from the same column.

```
select cust,date,data 
from cust_a1 where ai_code between '17' and '19';
```

This will return multiple rows

```
1234567 | 04-04-2011 | special offer
1234567 | 04-04-2011 | cheep offer
1345678 | 04-04-2011 | friday offer
1345678 | 04-04-2011 | special offer
```

I would like to shape it like this:

```
1234567 | 04-04-2011 | special offer | cheep offer
1345678 | 04-04-2011 | special offer | friday offer
```

How can this be done?

Comment: So you send spam emails then?

Comment: How many times can an ID repeat is there any limit (like 1234567 repeats twice in the first dataset)?

Comment: @asawyer - can your comments be a bit constructive please ?

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Can you do this in code (PHP, c#, etc) or does this have to be done at the sql level?

Comment: Take a look at sum(case( ....  )) syntax

Comment: @Uw Concept - Usually I'd agree.  Today I agree with asawyer.  This is like helping a con man.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually known as a [PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)