# Display table in different format

Tags: sql-server

i have the sql code that returns the result

```
Set1   Value
A       A1      
A       A2
A       A3
A       A4
```

How do i display the result like this

```
Set1    Value1      Value2       Value3      Value4
A           A1        A2           A3          A4
```

Thanks

Comment: i was wondering exactly the same thing in the morning. :)

Comment: You may be able to achieve this with Common Table Expression.  I am not sure though.  What would you need this behavior for?

Comment: Please tag and/or specify the version of SQL Server you are using. In 2005+ you can use PIVOT but there's little sense coding a solution if it's not going to be valid.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this

[SQL Server: Examples of PIVOTing String data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Following would do the trick. Using `ROW_NUMBER` allows for values other than `A1`-`A4`

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  [Set1] = Set1
        , [Value1] = MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Value END)
        , [Value2] = MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Value END)
        , [Value3] = MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Value END)
        , [Value4] = MIN(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN Value END)
FROM    (       
            SELECT  Set1
                    , Value
                    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Set1 ORDER BY Value)
            FROM    AResult
        ) q
GROUP BY
        Set1
```