# Create table using rows from another table as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, create-table

I have a table with the following structure :

**TableNo1**

Field1

row1

row2

row3

row4

row5

...

...

...

row n

Now I need to create a new table with the following schema:

**TableNo2**

Field1(row1 of Table1)   Field2(row2 of Table1)   Field3(row3 of table1) Fieldn(row n of table1)

I read about this but only thing i was able to find is the into clause which doesnt work.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples][1]

Comment: I wanna create a new table!!!!! The rows of table1 will be the columns of table2....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @TableNo1 TABLE(Field varchar(128),DataType varchar(128))
DECLARE @s nvarchar(max)='CREATE TABLE dbo.TableNo2('
INSERT INTO @TableNo1
VALUES
('Field1','nvarchar(max)'),
('Field2','int')

SELECT  @s+=T.Field+' '+T.DataType+',' FROM   @TableNo1 T
SET @s=LEFT(@s,LEN(@s)-1)+')'
EXECUTE(@s)
```