# Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to convert rows to column in SQL Server 2008 using table valued function?

Example:

```
Name: Danish; Sex: Male
```

convert to `Male` as column heading and `Danish` as field data.

Thanks,
Danish

Comment: You mean you want to convert a string to a table? What are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really vague.

Converting rows to columns in sql server can be done with the PIVOT function. Look at the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx), and maybe [this stackoverflow question for examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples).

I fail to see what this has to do with table-valued functions