# SQL Stored procedure, Output rows as columns for summary

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, macros

Using SQL 2005
Here is what my SQL results look like

```
UserID | Frame | Choice | Description | DateTime
------------------------------------------------
bcn005 | PL_P03| 1      | Rules-Based | 2011-10-24 14:14:26
bcn005 | PL_P04| 0      | VirtueBased | 2011-10-24 14:16:37
...
bmk172 | Prac_1| 0      | None        | 2011-10-25 12:45:38
...
```

My client wants the results to look like this

```
UserID | Frame | Choice | Description | DateTime  | Frame | Choice | Description | DateTime 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bcn005 | PL_P03| 1      | Rules-Based | 2011-10-..| PL_P04| 0      | VirtueBased | 2011-10-..
bmk172 | Prac_1| 0      | None        | 2011-10-..|
```

Where all of a participants responses are on one row.  There basically needs to be another set of Frame/Choice Description/DateTime for every row of the result set.

These are survey results, but it is the type of survey where one participant might have went back and changed their answer 5 times.  So the amount of Frame/Choice Description/DateTime for each UserID will be different.

I know I should use a stored procedure (or maybe even an excel macro) but I am completely new to both of these. Any guidance is appreciated. Here is my SQL query

```
select UserID, locationName AS 'Frame', student_response AS 'Choice',
description, DateTime
from tblStudentResponses
WHERE GroupID in (18,20,21,36,37,38,39,40)
AND UserID in (SELECT UserID FROM tblStudentResponses WHERE
locationName = 'Character1Certificate')
AND DateTime > '2011-10-01'
AND type = 'choice'
order by UserID
```

---

**!! UPDATE !!** Full working solution and test code

---

--Sample Data Preperation
DECLARE @FrameChoices as TABLE(UserId varchar(50),Frame varchar(50),Choice varchar(4000),Description varchar(1000),[DateTime] DateTime)

```
--Test Values
INSERT INTO @FrameChoices(UserId,Frame,Choice,Description,[DateTime])
SELECT  UserId,Frame,Choice,Description,[DateTime]
FROM (
    SELECT 'bcn005' AS UserId, 'PL_P03' AS Frame, '1' AS Choice, 'Rules-Based'
    AS Description, '2011-10-24 14:14:26' AS [DateTime]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bcn005' AS UserId, 'PL_P04' AS Frame, '0' AS Choice, 'VirtueBased'
    AS Description, '2011-10-24 14:16:37' AS [DateTime]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bmk172' AS UserId, 'Prac_1' AS Frame, '0' AS Choice, 'None' AS
    Description, '2011-10-25 12:45:38' AS [DateTime]
) T
```

-- Dynamic SQL Preparation

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @MaxNumberOfFrames INT

SET @SQL = ''
SET @MaxNumberOfFrames = 1

SELECT @MaxNumberOfFrames = MAX(FrameCount)
  FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(1) FrameCount
        FROM @FrameChoices
        GROUP BY UserId  
    ) T

 --needed to be part of the SQL string to EXEC at the bottom
SET @SQL = 'DECLARE @FrameChoices as TABLE(UserId varchar(50),Frame varchar(50),Choice varchar(4000),Description varchar(1000),[DateTime] DateTime)' 

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' INSERT INTO @FrameChoices(UserId,Frame,Choice,Description,[DateTime])'
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' SELECT  UserId,Frame,Choice,Description,[DateTime]'
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM ('
SET @SQL = @SQL + '     SELECT ''bcn005'' AS UserId, ''PL_P03'' AS Frame, ''1'' AS Choice, ''Rules-Based'''
SET @SQL = @SQL + '     AS Description, ''2011-10-24 14:14:26'' AS [DateTime]'
SET @SQL = @SQL + '     UNION ALL'
SET @SQL = @SQL + '     SELECT ''bcn005'' AS UserId, ''PL_P04'' AS Frame, ''0'' AS Choice, ''VirtueBased'''
SET @SQL = @SQL + '     AS Description, ''2011-10-24 14:16:37'' AS [DateTime]'
SET @SQL = @SQL + '     UNION ALL'
SET @SQL = @SQL + '     SELECT ''bmk172'' AS UserId, ''Prac_1'' AS Frame, ''0'' AS Choice, ''None'' AS'
SET @SQL = @SQL + '     Description, ''2011-10-25 12:45:38'' AS [DateTime]'
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' ) T'

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' SELECT UserId'

--changed size to max
DECLARE @ColumnSQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @CurrentFrame INT

SET @CurrentFrame = 1

WHILE (@CurrentFrame <= @MaxNumberOfFrames)
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnSQL = ', MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber ='+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)+ ' THEN Frame ELSE '''' END) AS Frame_'+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)
                    + ', MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber ='+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)+ ' THEN Choice ELSE '''' END) AS Choice_'+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)
                    + ', MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber ='+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)+ ' THEN Description ELSE '''' END) AS Description_'+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)
                    + ', MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber ='+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)+ ' THEN [DateTime] ELSE NULL END) AS DateTime_'+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @ColumnSQL
    SET @CurrentFrame = @CurrentFrame + 1
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM ( SELECT UserId,Frame,Choice,Description,[DateTime], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY [DateTime]) AS RowNumber FROM @FrameChoices) T GROUP BY T.UserId'

PRINT @SQL
```

-- This generated SQL then can be executed by

```
EXEC(@SQL)
 -- OR
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@SQL)
```

-- Sample SQL generated from above query

```
DECLARE @FrameChoices as TABLE(UserId varchar(50),Frame varchar(50),Choice varchar(4000),Description varchar(1000),[DateTime] DateTime) INSERT INTO @FrameChoices(UserId,Frame,Choice,Description,[DateTime]) SELECT  UserId,Frame,Choice,Description,[DateTime] FROM (     SELECT 'bcn005' AS UserId, 'PL_P03' AS Frame, '1' AS Choice, 'Rules-Based'  AS Description, '2011-10-24 14:14:26' AS [DateTime]     UNION ALL   SELECT 'bcn005' AS UserId, 'PL_P04' AS Frame, '0' AS Choice, 'VirtueBased'  AS Description, '2011-10-24 14:16:37' AS [DateTime]     UNION ALL   SELECT 'bmk172' AS UserId, 'Prac_1' AS Frame, '0' AS Choice, 'None' AS  Description, '2011-10-25 12:45:38' AS [DateTime] ) T SELECT UserId, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =1 THEN Frame ELSE '' END) AS Frame_1, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =1 THEN Choice ELSE '' END) AS Choice_1, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =1 THEN Description ELSE '' END) AS Description_1, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =1 THEN [DateTime] ELSE NULL END) AS DateTime_1, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =2 THEN Frame ELSE '' END) AS Frame_2, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =2 THEN Choice ELSE '' END) AS Choice_2, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =2 THEN Description ELSE '' END) AS Description_2, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =2 THEN [DateTime] ELSE NULL END) AS DateTime_2 FROM ( SELECT UserId,Frame,Choice,Description,[DateTime], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY [DateTime]) AS RowNumber FROM @FrameChoices) T GROUP BY T.UserId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SQL 2005 or ABove you can try pivot.

If SQL 2000, then use combination of Group By and Case.

```
SELECT GC1,
       GC2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CONDITION1 THEN Value1 ELSE Value2 END) AS DerivedColumn
FROM Table1
GROUP BY GC1, GC2
```

References:
[SQL Server PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/)

[Pivot with Dynamic Column](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx)

[Stack Overflow Pivot Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

[Solution]

-- Sample Data Preparation

```
DECLARE @FrameChoices TABLE
(
  UserId varchar(20),
  Frame varchar(20),
  Choice int,
  Description varchar(20),
  [DateTime] DateTime
)

INSERT INTO @FrameChoices(UserId,Frame,Choice,Description,[DateTime])
SELECT  UserId,Frame,Choice,Description,[DateTime]
  FROM (
        SELECT 'bcn005' AS UserId, 'PL_P03' AS Frame, 1 AS Choice, 'Rules-Based' AS Description, '2011-10-24 14:14:26' AS [DateTime]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'bcn005' AS UserId, 'PL_P04' AS Frame, 0 AS Choice, 'VirtueBased' AS Description, '2011-10-24 14:16:37' AS [DateTime]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'bmk172' AS UserId, 'Prac_1' AS Frame, 0 AS Choice, 'None' AS Description, '2011-10-25 12:45:38' AS [DateTime]
       ) T
```

-- Dynamic SQL Preparation

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @MaxNumberOfFrames INT

SET @SQL = ''
SET @MaxNumberOfFrames = 1

SELECT @MaxNumberOfFrames = MAX(FrameCount)
  FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(1)FrameCount
  FROM @FrameChoices
 GROUP BY UserId  
) T

SET @SQL = 'SELECT UserId'

DECLARE @ColumnSQL VARCHAR(512)
DECLARE @CurrentFrame INT

SET @CurrentFrame = 1

WHILE (@CurrentFrame <= @MaxNumberOfFrames)
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnSQL = ', MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber ='+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)+ ' THEN Frame ELSE NULL END) AS Frame_'+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)
                    + ', MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber ='+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)+ ' THEN Choice ELSE NULL END) AS Choice_'+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)
                    + ', MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber ='+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)+ ' THEN Description ELSE NULL END) AS Description_'+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)
                    + ', MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber ='+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)+ ' THEN [DateTime] ELSE NULL END) AS DateTime_'+CAST(@CurrentFrame AS VARCHAR)
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @ColumnSQL
    SET @CurrentFrame = @CurrentFrame + 1
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + ' FROM ( SELECT UserId,Frame,Choice,Description,[DateTime], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY [DateTime]) AS RowNumber FROM @FrameChoices) T GROUP BY T.UserId'

PRINT @SQL
```

-- This generated SQL then can be executed by

```
EXEC(@SQL)
 -- OR
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL(@SQL)
```

-- Sample SQL generated from above query

```
SELECT UserId, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =1 THEN Frame ELSE NULL END) AS Frame_1, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =1 THEN Choice ELSE NULL END) AS Choice_1, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =1 THEN Description ELSE NULL END) AS Description_1, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =1 THEN [DateTime] ELSE NULL END) AS DateTime_1, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =2 THEN Frame ELSE NULL END) AS Frame_2, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =2 THEN Choice ELSE NULL END) AS Choice_2, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =2 THEN Description ELSE NULL END) AS Description_2, MAX(CASE WHEN RowNumber =2 THEN [DateTime] ELSE NULL END) AS DateTime_2 FROM ( SELECT UserId,Frame,Choice,Description,[DateTime], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY [DateTime]) AS RowNumber FROM @FrameChoices) T GROUP BY T.UserId
```

Comment: These examples would allow me to pivot the frame names into columns.  I need to actually keep the columns I have in my query but add a new set of frame/choice/description/datetime for every row.

Comment: So it seems columns would be dynamic, only way to do it by a query is dynamic sql. Link in answer "Pivot with Dynamic Column" will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I know my answer is in there, but I am having a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: I have implemented the sample solution, check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! It worked.  To get results I had to declare as a table variable and include my query twice. Once to create the columns and once in the @sql string to build the data.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the Pivot Table functionality of SQL Server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: See comment on Nitin Midha answer above.  I am trying to make new columns for every row not change column values into columns.