# Is is possible to have dynamic COUNT (CASE WHEN ) statement?

Tags: sql, case-when

I have SQL query and it works OK.

```
select monthname (timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE)), 

    count (case when service='ADSL' then 1 end) as  ADSL,
    count (case when service='IPTV' then 1 end) as  IPTV,
    count (case when service='VOIP' then 1 end) as  VOIP
from INCIDENT
group by monthname(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE))
```

I am getting for each month number of services in that month.
But these services I have over 100. 
Is it possible to have dynamic CASE WHEN? To get all services and for each service return number of them in that month. Also it should write me after AS name of the service.
Another option is to I write those 100 services manually so I was just wondering?
Thanks

Comment: What database are you using?  Is dynamic SQL an option?

Comment: please accept an answer which is correct for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a dynamic number of columns in SQL.

You can write code (In SQL or another language) that writes SQL to execute (Dynamic SQL), but that can get messy.  WSo, the resulting SQL Query is for a fixed number of columns, but you have code that changes the SQL Query each time you run it.

The standard Relational Database Model that fits your needs, and that doesn't need dynamic recoding, is to normalise your results...

```
SELECT
  monthname (timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE)),
  service,
  COUNT(*) AS count_service
FROM
  incident
GROUP BY
  monthname(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE)),
  service
```

The question then becomes: *Do you Really need a pivotted result set when you don't know how many columns you'll get?*

Comment: Alternatively, if it's always the same 100, and you just want to save time typing... Copy the 100 values into EXCEL and use that two build the case statements for you. Then copy them back into SQL.

Comment: OK thanks...I have now over 100 so I will write them it is OK but maybe in future they will add some more services so I would like to SQL code pick it up automatically instead of me adding in code but OK. Can you just clarify me what is the pivotted result set? Because I am not sure if that is what I want. You were right I would like to have somehow dynamic number of columns

Comment: @Dejan - Normalised results are as per my answer. Pivotted results are as per your question. It just means to take rows and make them into columns. The up side is that it is more human friendly. The down side is that it is less SQL friendly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this, in a programming language you can `select DISTINCT service` and build your query

For example in C#

```
string SQL = "select monthname (timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE))" 

List<string> Columns = new List<string>();
foreach(string service in Services)
{
     Columns.Add( "  count (case when service='"+service+"' then 1 end) as  "+service);
}

SQL +="," + String.Join(",",Columns.ToArray());
SQL += " from INCIDENT group by monthname(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE))";

db.Query(SQL);
```

in Javascript:

```
  var SQL = "select monthname (timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE))"; 

var Columns = new Array();
foreach(string service in Services)
{
     Columns.push( "  count (case when service='"+service+"' then 1 end) as  "+service);
}

SQL +="," + Columns.Join(',');
SQL += " from INCIDENT group by monthname(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE))";

db.Query(SQL);
```

other way if you use oracle you can try write PL/SQL to select columns, and build your query dynamicly, then use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` Statement

Comment: Just be careful that the `service` values aren't human generated.  Or that you use paramterised queries instead.  (With a dynamic number of parameters).

Comment: And what if any of the values in that column contain `'`?

Comment: Thanks but I am not working in a programming language. I am working in BIRT reporting tool. It only supports javascript. Maybe I could combine SQL with javascript?

Comment: also javascript has a strong string manipulating. yes you can.

Comment: you don't know maybe what is equivalent  for Add and Join methods?

Comment: Create an array for columns.  var Columns = Array();  use Columns.push() instead of Add, and    Columns.Join(',') direclty :)

Comment: I just added the js example to my answer hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    service,
    monthname (timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE)), 
    count (*)              
from 
    INCIDENT
where 
    service in ('ADSL','IPTV','VOIP')
group by 
    monthname(timestamp_iso(STATUSDATE)), 
    service
```

I think this gets you close to what you want.

Comment: In this query each service will be in a row, I think he want get a column for each service.

Comment: sure but I think he just wants the data if you slice left to right or up and down... the data he wants to look at is there.

Comment: You may want to look at this post for how to pivot this.. if you really want to... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples

Comment: thanks for reply but because of making some reports in BIRT I must have columns instead of rows. With rows I can not make graphic but thanks anyway