# Is it possible to generate columns based on a query in an SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I'm trying to generate a security matrix as a report for my application.

Looking at this question, it is almost exactly what I want.

[SQL Server: Examples of PIVOTing String data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

I've changed the solution

```
SELECT Action,
   MAX( CASE data WHEN 'View' THEN data ELSE '' END ) ViewCol, 
   MAX( CASE data WHEN 'Edit' THEN data ELSE '' END ) EditCol
FROM t
GROUP BY Action
```

to adapt to my solution.

```
SELECT RefRoleId ,
       MAX( CASE Permission WHEN 'AdministerErrors' THEN 'X' ELSE '' END ) 'Administer Errors'
 FROM RolePermission
 GROUP BY RefRoleId
```

The problem I can see though is that I would need to know exactly which permissions I have and hard code them as columns into the query. I would need a new

MAX( CASE Permission WHEN 'AdministerErrors' THEN 'X' ELSE '' END ) 'Administer Errors'

for every single permission.

Is there a way for me to add the columns I want displayed to an SQL query via a query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can build your pivot dynamically, automatically adding as many columns as you need, based on the data in the table. Step-by-step instructions: http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx

The article doesn't mention SQL Server 2008, but it works with that version as well.