# Rotate SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table like below

```
Code        Attribute        Value
--------------------------------------
USA         Population       300M
USA         Language         US English
CANADA      Population       30M
USA         Capital          DC
CANADA      Language         CA English
```

How can I rotate table for 90 degrees and make a **view** like below to run ***query*** and ***sp*** on it?

```
Code        Language        Population       Capital
------------------------------------------------------
USA         US English         300M              DC
CANADA      CA English          30M              NULL
```

Comment: The term for rotating a table 90 degrees is called a `PIVOT`.

Comment: see this question: [SQL Server PIVOT examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `PIVOT` (for SQL Server 2005+):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable AS T
PIVOT (MIN(Value) FOR Attribute IN ([Language],[Population],[Capital]) AS PT
```

For all version of SQL Server you can use this:

```
SELECT  Code, 
        MIN(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'Language' THEN Value END) [Language],
        MIN(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'Population' THEN Value END) [Population],
        MIN(CASE WHEN Attribute = 'Capital' THEN Value END) [Capital]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Code
```