# Union, Join, Or GroupBy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have procedures pulling data from various sources to give me 3 VERY similar tables.

```
Metric          | Tickets   |Band
______________________________________
Acknowledgement | 45        | New
Acknowledgement | 23        | Within
Acknowledgement | 16        | Near
Acknowledgement | 2         | Very Near
```

And

```
Metric     | Tickets   |Band
___________________________________
Escalation | 10        | New
Escalation | 43        | Within
Escalation | 81        | Near
Escalation | 6         | Very Near
```

And

```
Metric| Tickets   |Band
___________________________________
Fixed | 34        | New
Fixed | 52        | Within
Fixed | 36        | Near
Fixed | 4         | Very Near
```

Now, I would like to combine them together in some way to have one table output like this

```
Metric          | New   | Within | Near | Very Near
_____________________________________________________
Acknowledgement | 45    | 23     | 16   | 2
Escalation      | 10    | 43     | 81   | 6
Fixed           | 34    | 52     | 36   | 4
```

How can I achieve this in MS SQLServer, please ?

Comment: Why don't you just have one table with all 12 of the entries in it?

Comment: This question and answers will give you lots of info - does is help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 - these sorts of questions are generally pointless...  Usually by the time a person is asking this sort of question, the schema is already defined and there is little that can be done to change it.

Comment: @StefanH I should reiterate my question then:  why doesn't OP just have a view with all 12 entries in it?  It would greatly simplify the problem.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 So,  that view would need to contain a query that did what?  Oh yeah, the query in that view would need to do what the OP is asking for in this question...

Comment: @StefanH A view with all of the records together combined with the answer PreetSangha linked would solve his problem.

Comment: What VERSION of SQL Server, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fake pivot that should get what you want.  You would then union this query for each table.

```
SELECT 
    Metric,
    MAX( CASE Band WHEN 'New' THEN Tickets ELSE '' END ) New, 
    MAX( CASE Band WHEN 'Within' THEN Tickets ELSE '' END ) Within, 
    MAX( CASE Band WHEN 'Near' THEN Tickets ELSE '' END ) Near, 
    MAX( CASE Band WHEN 'Very Near' THEN Tickets ELSE '' END ) [Very Near]
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    Metric

UNION
...
```

Comment: +1 but what's that `Tickets data` in the last aggregate?  Would also work with `SUM()` aggregates as in `SUM(CASE Band WHEN 'New' THEN Tickets ELSE 0 END) New`

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't require repeating all of the aggregates and CASE expressions for each table - just a simple union will do, then you can pivot off of that.

```
SELECT Metric, [New], [Within], [Near], [Very Near] FROM 
(
            SELECT Metric, Tickets, Band FROM dbo.table_a
  UNION ALL SELECT Metric, Tickets, Band FROM dbo.table_b
  UNION ALL SELECT Metric, Tickets, Band FROM dbo.table_c
) 
AS x PIVOT 
(
  MAX(Tickets) FOR Band IN ([New],[Within],[Near],[Very Near])
) AS p;
```

Comment: Yes this definitely is a better question.