# SQL Server two lines in one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Hello and thanks for your attention

I need to convert data from two different lines into one line.

Let s imagine

`ORDERS` table:

```
ID    Name    adress   
-------------------- 
01    AA      adr1
02    BB      adr2
03    CC      adr3
```

`LINEORDERS` table:

```
ID    IDorder    IDprofileType     ProfileType      idPers   
------------------------------------------------------------- 
01    01         01                Organizer        0045
01    01         02                Present          0085
01    01         02                Present          0032
01    01         03                Manager          0018
```

Lets imagine we want as result >

Desired result:

```
IDorder   NameOrder     OrganizerID           PresentID           ManagerID       Diff
------------------------------------------------------------- 
01        AA            0045                  0085                0018            yes
01        AA            0045                  0032                0018            yes
```

`Diff` is yes if `managerID` and `organizerID` are different.

How can I get such a result?

Do I need to create  T-SQL temporary tables? What would be the lighter?

I have a lot of lines in the table.

Thanks for your help

Comment: where to get yes?u can use concat with group by

Comment: @ArunKillu The question is about MS SQL Server and **not** MySQL

Comment: is there something like that in ms sql

Comment: @ArunKillu Nope, but lots of question about that topic (group_concat in SQL Server) here on SO, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server-2005 ;)

Comment: 10x @OcasoProtal for the info

Comment: "Diff is yes if managerID and organizerID are different." -> In your desired result they are not different. The only difference is PresentID.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with subqueries, but I really think that you must do some reengineering here. Cause there will be a lot of subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL Server, you should try PIVOT. Here are some examples: [SQL Server: Examples of PIVOTing String data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)