# Getting multiple rows from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

The problem I'm having is that there are more than one result in a table for what I'm trying to find. So if I have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT student.ident AS [Ident],
     proghist.prgc AS [Test Code]
FROM student 
LEFT OUTER JOIN proghist
```

For some students I get multiple "Test Codes" so it'll look like this:

```
Ident   Test Code
123456   1
123456   4
654321   2
654321   6
122222   1
```

Is there a way to combine them to one row and separate columns?

Edit:  I would like the data to be in the final result:

```
123456 1 4 
654321 2 6 
122222 1
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  What is the desired result of the query?  Do you want the `TestCode` values comma separated or in multiple columns?

Comment: try to use pivot, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples

Comment: I'm using MSSQL. I'm trying to get it to be something like:

`123456   1   4`
`654321   2   6`
`122222   1`

But on separate lines. Instead of what I have in the example above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using SQL Server, if you are using SQL Server 2005+, then you can use the `PIVOT` function.  If you know you will only have up to two `TestCodes` per `ident` then you can hard-code the values:

```
select ident,
  [1] TestCode1,
  [2] TestCode2
from
(
  SELECT  s.ident AS Ident,
    p.prgc AS TestCode,
    row_number() over(partition by s.ident order by p.prgc) rn
  FROM student s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN proghist p
    on s.ident = p.ident
) src
pivot
(
  max(TestCode)
  for rn in ([1], [2])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39a67/7)

If you have an unknown number of values of `TestCodes`, then you can use dynamic SQL to `PIVOT` the data:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(rn)
                    FROM
                    (
                      select cast(row_number() over(partition by s.ident order by p.prgc) as varchar(50)) rn
                      FROM student s
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN proghist p
                        on s.ident = p.ident
                    ) src
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(rn) + ' as TestCode'+rn
                    FROM
                    (
                      select cast(row_number() over(partition by s.ident order by p.prgc) as varchar(50)) rn
                      FROM student s
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN proghist p
                        on s.ident = p.ident
                    ) src
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Ident, ' + @colsPivot + ' from 
             (
               SELECT  s.ident AS Ident,
                p.prgc AS TestCode,
                row_number() over(partition by s.ident order by p.prgc) rn
              FROM student s
              LEFT OUTER JOIN proghist p
                on s.ident = p.ident
            ) src
            pivot 
            (
                max(TestCode)
                for rn in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4bf2/5)

If you do not have access to the `PIVOT` function, then you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
select ident,
  max(case when rn = 1 then testcode else '' end) TestCode1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then testcode else '' end) TestCode2
from
(
  SELECT  s.ident AS Ident,
    p.prgc AS TestCode,
    row_number() over(partition by s.ident order by p.prgc) rn
  FROM student s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN proghist p
    on s.ident = p.ident
) src
group by ident
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c4bf2/6)

All three will produce the same result:

```
|  IDENT | TESTCODE1 | TESTCODE2 |
----------------------------------
| 122222 |         1 |         0 |
| 123456 |         1 |         4 |
| 654321 |         2 |         6 |
```