# Return values from multiple rows as columns with group by on multiple colum

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to return multiple row values into colum by group by on multiple column

with distinct.

If my table is:

QUantityTypeID    Quantity       OrderDate           CompanyID           TypeName

--------------           --------        -----------        ----------------        ----------

1                            7.0000          2013-09-02             1                    Sales

1                          4.0000        2013-09-15             1                  Sales

1                          1.0000      2013-09-16        1                      Sales

1                          1.0000      2013-09-16           2                    Sales

2                          1.0000      2013-08-25           1                  Sales

3                          1.0000      2013-08-25           1                  Sales

4                          1.0000      2013-09-11           1                  Sales

The select should return:

OrderDate               1               2               3                 4            CompanyID           TypeName

-----------             -----        -----           ------      ------      ----------------          ----------

2013-08-25       NULL      1.0000    1.0000    NULL      1      Sales

2013-09-02       7.0000    NULL      NULL      NULL      1      Sales

2013-09-11       NULL      NULL      NULL      1.0000      1      Sales

2013-09-15       4.0000    NULL      NULL      NULL      1      Sales

2013-09-16       1.0000    NULL      NULL      NULL      1      Sales

2013-09-16       1.0000    NULL      NULL      NULL      2      Sales

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples/40434#40434

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pivot your data.

```
SELECT
  OrderDate, [1], [2], [3], [4], CompanyID, TypeName 
FROM test
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Quantity)
  FOR QUantityTypeID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) as p
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a6f6c/1)**