# Convert rows to columns with where condition SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I'm looking for a quick efficient way to convert:

```
ID  Type       Amount
0   Damages    1
0   Other      2
1   Damages    3
1   Other      4
2   Damages    5
2   Other      6
```

To

```
ID Damages Other
0  1       2
1  3       4
2  5       6
```

There are around 200,000 records in the table, using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: You are supposed to attempt something..

Comment: I didn't know where to start, hence no attempt sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server PIVOT examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways that you can get the result.  You can use a CASE expression with an aggregate function:

```
select id,
  sum(case when type ='Damages' then amount else 0 end) damages,
  sum(case when type ='Other' then amount else 0 end) other
from yourtable
group by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/235f3/1). Or since you are using SQL Server 2008, then you can use the PIVOT function:

```
select id, Damages, Other
from yourtable
pivot
(
  sum(amount)
  for type in (Damages, Other)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/235f3/2)

Comment: Is either method more efficient or no difference?

Comment: @Jammy You will have to test on your system (indexes, etc) but aggregate with CASE _tends_ to be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks just wondered.