# Create columns based on data in existing column, duplicate data exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Acct    MasterAcct 
------- -------------
123     M01  
123     M02  
234     M03  
345     M04  
456     M05  
456     M06  
456     M07
```

I'd like to break the MasterAcct column into three columns (Master1, Master2, Master3).  An account can have up to three master accounts associated with it.  Example output from the previous table would have account #456 on one row and then the three master account numbers in Master1, Master2, and Master3.  Can anyone help?

---

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server PIVOT examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

Comment: Which version of sql server are you use?

Comment: I use sql server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` in conjunction with `ROW_NUMBER()` ranking function.

```
SELECT Acct, [1] as [Master1], [2] as [Master2], [3] as [Master3]
FROM
  (
      SELECT Acct, 
            MasterAcct, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY acct ORDER BY MasterAcct) as mid
      FROM tbl
   ) as t
PIVOT
(
   MIN(MasterAcct)
   FOR mid IN ([1], [2], [3])
) as p
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ee26/6)**

You can achieve the same result without using `PIVOT`. The following query is easy to understand.

```
SELECT
    Acct,
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid=1 THEN MasterAcct END) as [Master1],
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid=2 THEN MasterAcct END) as [Master2],
    MAX(CASE WHEN mid=3 THEN MasterAcct END) as [Master3]
FROM
   (
      SELECT Acct, 
            MasterAcct, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY acct ORDER BY MasterAcct) as mid
      FROM tbl
   ) t
GROUP BY Acct
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ee26/9)**

Comment: Thanks hamlet. Can we do this without partition and row number ? Also, can you please explain the logic here ? I ask because I only know how to do simple pivots.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That worked perfectly.  I'm very new to SQL, so I would also like to understand the logic behind it.  Thanks again