# MSSql result of query in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new in SQL. I have three tables. TableA, TabelB and TableC. I have a request

```
SELECT a.Name, b.Value, c.Value
FROM dbo.TableA a
join dbo.TableB b ON a.Id=b.AValue
join dbo.TableC c ON b.Id=c.CValue
WHERE a.Object='ObjectName'
```

So I have a result like:

```
Name  |ValueB |Value
---------------------
MyName|MyValue|1Value 
---------------------
MyName|MyValue|2Value
---------------------
MyNaem|MyValue|3Value
```

So, how should I change request to get:

```
Name  |ValueB |Value |Value |Value
----------------------------------
MyName|MyValue|1Value|2Value|3Value
```

Is it possible?

Comment: On what basis? You need to show some real values.

Comment: You're asking for one ValueB columns and three Value columns, but from which tables are these Value columns? You need to be consistent with your names and show the structure of the tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server PIVOT examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples).  In any case, you _are_ looking to do a `PIVOT`, of which there are a multitude of examples available.