# SQL Query - return row values as columns

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
Part    X   Y   
ABC     1   10  
ABC     2   20  
ABC     3   30  
ABC     4   40  
ABC     5   x   
ABC     6   x   
XYZ     1   50  
XYZ     2   60  
XYZ     3   70  
XYZ     4   80  
XYZ     5   x   
XYZ     6   x   
ETC     1   90  
ETC     2   100 
ETC     3   110
```

Id like to select this data in the following way:

```
Part    1   2   3   4
ABC     10  20  30  40
XYZ     50  60  70  80
ETC     90  110 120 130
```

Is this possible?

Notes:

- Header for results = 1,2,3,4 = Field x from the table
- FieldX contains values 1 - 18, I'm only interested in 1-4
- I'd later like to also Join this to a product table where I'll be able to specify the results based on the product.Supplier field.

I think Subqueries may be the way to go but not experienced in this area.

Thanks for any help offered

Comment: This is called pivoting and the solution depends on the database you are using. Eg SQL Server has the PIVOT/UNPIVOT commands, others use a combination of GROUP BY and conditionals. What database are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples -- lots and lots of SO answers on this one...

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos I'm using SQL Server 2008 - thanks for the Pivot suggestion.  I'll investigate and mark the answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only posting this as the previous answers seem way off.  Without knowing your `RDBMS`, you can use `MAX` with `CASE`:

```
SElECT part,
    MAX(CASE WHEN X = 1 THEN Y END) Y1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN X = 2 THEN Y END) Y2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN X = 3 THEN Y END) Y3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN X = 4 THEN Y END) Y4
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY part
```

If you're RDBMS will support it, you can use the `PIVOT` command.

Comment: Pivot may be the better way to achieve this but unfortunately not available on my database.

I then used suggestion above and managed to get it working.

Many thanks to all suggestions - marked as answer