# MS SQL 2008 - Transpose rows into columns

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an attendance table whose structure is like this.

```
CREATE TABLE ATTENDANCE(
EmployeeID VARCHAR(10),
LogDate DATETIME);
```

Supposse following values are there in the table:

```
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('1','2014-06-25 09:30:00:00')
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('1','2014-06-25 13:20:00:00')
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('1','2014-06-25 15:40:00:00')
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('1','2014-06-25 18:21:00:00')

INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('2','2014-06-25 08:31:00:00')
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('2','2014-06-25 14:21:00:00')
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('2','2014-06-25 16:43:00:00')
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('2','2014-06-25 19:22:00:00')

INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('1','2014-06-26 09:30:00:00')
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('1','2014-06-26 13:20:00:00')
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('1','2014-06-26 15:40:00:00')
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('1','2014-06-26 18:21:00:00')

INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('2','2014-06-26 08:31:00:00')
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('2','2014-06-26 14:21:00:00')
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('2','2014-06-26 16:43:00:00')
INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE VALUES('2','2014-06-26 19:22:00:00')
```

I want to display the data like below:

```
Emp ID    Attendance Date    Log 1          Log 2          Log 3          Log 4
1         25-04-2014         09:30:00:00    13:20:00:00    15:40:00:00    18:21:00:00
2         25-04-2014         08:31:00:00    14:21:00:00    16:43:00:00    19:22:00:00
1         26-04-2014         09:30:00:00    13:20:00:00    15:40:00:00    18:21:00:00
2         26-04-2014         08:31:00:00    14:21:00:00    16:43:00:00    19:22:00:00
```

Please help me frame this query.

Thanks,

Rajesh

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server PIVOT examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

Comment: Here the Attendance Date column and Log1, Log2,....... could be multiple in numbers and couldn't be ascertained before framing the query. That is where I am stuck.

Comment: The only way then will be a dynamic query. Does the log columns are numerated always starting from 1, and does al the employees have the same number of logs every date?

Comment: Yes, every time the report would be generated, the log columns will be numerated from 1. Employee may have different number of logs every day.