# How to pivot column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

i'm try to pivot column but it's still error about "Invalid column name"

this is my data in sql server

[image]

this is my code

```
 select EARCBG_Abbrev, EARCIM_Code, EITP_Price, ETAR_Desc
 from EMR_OrderItem
 pivot (count(EITP_Price) for ETAR_Desc in ([OPD], [IPD], [Tourist])) as showpavot
 where EARCIM_Code = '010004'
```

Can you tell how can i do in this case and tell me why ? 
Thank you so much.

this is my result when i try your code

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server PIVOT examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PIVOT, you either need to use subquery to select all of your columns and then your final list includes your "new" pivoted columns similar to this:

```
select EARCBG_Abbrev,
  EARCIM_Code,
  [OPD], [IPD], [Tourist]
from
(
  select EARCBG_Abbrev, EARCIM_Code, EITP_Price, ETAR_Desc
  from EMR_OrderItem
  where EARCIM_Code = '010004'
) d
pivot 
(
  count(EITP_Price) 
  for ETAR_Desc in ([OPD], [IPD], [Tourist])
) as showpavot;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80ea5/1/0)

Or you could write the query like this:

```
select 
  EARCBG_Abbrev,
  EARCIM_Code,
  [OPD], [IPD], [Tourist]
from EMR_OrderItem
pivot 
(
  count(EITP_Price) 
  for ETAR_Desc in ([OPD], [IPD], [Tourist])
) as showpavot
where EARCIM_Code = '010004';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/80ea5/2/0)

In both versions you'll see that the final select list includes the column names that you create during the pivot process.

This could also be written using an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select
  EARCBG_Abbrev,
  EARCIM_Code,
  sum(case when ETAR_Desc = 'OPD' then EITP_Price else 0 end) OPD,
  sum(case when ETAR_Desc = 'IPD' then EITP_Price else 0 end) IPD,
  sum(case when ETAR_Desc = 'Tourist' then EITP_Price else 0 end) Tourist
from EMR_OrderItem
where EARCIM_Code = '010004'
group by EARCBG_Abbrev, EARCIM_Code
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bdbb4/4)

Comment: Thank u so much .please check my answer result when i try your code

Comment: @user3001046 is the value of `EARCBG_Abbrev` exactly the same in all 3 rows? That value is also used in the GROUP BY so if it is not the same you will return multiple rows

Comment: In 3 rows is the same value

Comment: @user3001046 Can you create a sql fiddle with some sample data?

Comment: i see your demo it is the same solution why the result is not the same.

Comment: @user3001046 I'm asking you to create a sql fiddle with some of your actual data to see if I can replicate the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56551/discussion-between-bluefeet-and-user3001046).

Comment: then i try to group by EARCBG_Abbrev but it's still error about "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'showpavot.EARCIM_Code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
"

Answer (score 0):

After you perform a pivot, the first two columns mentioned in the `PIVOT` (referred to in MSDN [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177634.aspx) as the value column and the pivot column) no longer exist in the result set: `EITP_Price` was aggregated over to construct new values, and `ETAR_Desc` has become 3 separate columns:

```
select EARCBG_Abbrev, EARCIM_Code, [OPD], [IPD], [Tourist]
 from EMR_OrderItem
 pivot (count(EITP_Price) for ETAR_Desc in ([OPD], [IPD], [Tourist])) as showpavot
 where EARCIM_Code = '010004'
```