# SQL Server - Get count for each pharmacy's outbound usage for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query to select the total outbound usage of each pharmacy in my database table for each month.

Here is what I have so far, it outputs the correct data. But I want to eliminate the amount of rows selected

```
select pharmacyid, count(*) as usage, month(datecalled) as month
from outboundcalldata
where datepart(year, datecalled) = 2014
group by pharmacyid, YEAR(DateCalled), month(datecalled)
order by pharmacyid, month
```

example of output:

```
pharmacyid|usage| month
-----------------------
2220000006| 10  |  2
2220000006| 11  |  3
2220000006| 900 |  4
2220000006| 30  |  5
2220000007| 34  |  2
2220000007| 300 |  3
2220000007| 145 |  4
```

Instead I would like it to output 1 row per pharmacy and a column for each month.

Comment: "But I want to eliminate the amount of rows selected"  <--- what does this mean?  Show a sample data set, too

Comment: I think you want to pivot the results.  Google `sql server pivot`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24470

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
 select pharmacyid, count(*) as usage, month(datecalled) as [month]
 from outboundcalldata
 where datepart(year, datecalled) = 2014
 group by pharmacyid, YEAR(DateCalled), month(datecalled)
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE C
 PIVOT (SUM(usage)
        FOR [month]
        IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])
        )p
```