# SQL Server statement output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table structure

```
TicketID    Status  Duration
-----------------------------
1234           8        2
1233           8       10
1232           4        5
1231           8       12
1230           4       50
```

- status 8 means Closed
- status 4 means Open

It is required to have output in following way. Please do the need ful. If possible I wanted it in a single sql query.

Please help me to produce output in following way.

```
Status  Closed (sum)    Open(Sum)
---------------------------------
   8       24              0
   4        0             55
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Did you try anything at all ? Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

Comment: @SandipkTatva You might be looking for `GROUP BY` (links posted in the comments above), or `PIVOT` if your actual case is more complex than what you posted (i.e. there are more statuses in reality, etc) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples

Answer (score 0):

A `case` expression could filter out the unwanted values, so this can be done in a single aggregate query:

```
SELECT   status, 
         SUM (CASE status WHEN 8 THEN duration ELSE 0 END) AS closed_sum,
         SUM (CASE status WHEN 4 THEN duration ELSE 0 END) AS open_sum
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select status
       , sum( case when status = 4 then Duration else 0 end ) as [Open(sum)]
       , sum( case when status = 8 then Duration else 0 end ) as [Closed(sum)]
from @test
group by status
order by status desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH T AS (SELECT Status, SUM(Duration) AS Duration FROM Table1 GROUP BY Status)
SELECT Status, Duration, 0 FROM T WHERE Status = 8
UNION ALL
SELECT Status, 0, Duration FROM T WHERE Status = 4
```

Comment: To produce the EXACT expected output. I am aware that the WITH part gives all the information needed. The UNION part is to produce the EXPECTED output in the question. See the format in the question.

Answer (score 0):

use union all

```
    SELECT [Status],sum([Duration]) [Closed(sum)], '0' as   [Open(Sum)]
             from [dbo].[tblx] 
             where [Status]=8
             GROUP BY [Status] 


UNION all            
              SELECT [Status], '0' as [Closed(sum)],sum([Duration]) [Close(sum)]
             from [dbo].[tblx] 
             WHERE [Status]=4
             GROUP BY [Status]
```

[image]