# can someone explain purpose of "Select view_edit FROM tbl WHERE t.action = action"

Tags: sql

I'm trying to follow this code

[SQL Server: Examples of PIVOTing String data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

I've imported the table into sql server, and see that

"Select view_edit FROM tbl WHERE t.action = action" does

give me the view_edit that is in "select * from tbl"  but I am clueless why the author used this line of code.

Comment: Please paste all the **relevant** code here rather than linking to it, so that the question makes sense even if the link goes dead.

Comment: There is a whole bunch of codes in that link. Please paste relevant codes...

Comment: just do a find and you'll find the code.  Code is by mxasim

Comment: Why would you assume people will spend their time finding the code for your problem when you don't even bother spending your own time pasting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too big to put in a comment, so adding it in answer section

i think you are referring to this SQL code.

```
SELECT Action, 
[View] = (Select view_edit FROM tbl WHERE t.action = action and view_edit = 'VIEW'),
[Edit] = (Select view_edit FROM tbl WHERE t.action = action and view_edit = 'EDIT')
FROM tbl t
GROUP BY Action
```

Here correlated subquery is used instead of MAX aggregation or `pivot` keyword 
for each action in the table , the corresponding view_edit value is fetched in the correlated sub query , if  corresponding action is not found then it will have NULL

To understand more remove `group by` and run the query and you will understand the correlated subquery and the need for `group by`