# Group By and Add Multiple Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

Hi I have here some question. 

Here is my sample database

```
001 | A | AC 
001 | B | AC 
002 | A | IN 
002 | C | AC 
003 | A | AC
```

**Notes**

```
Column 1 - Should be the column header 
Column 2 - Should be the row header 
Column 3 - Should be the data
```

how can I create a table to make it look like this

```
- | 001 | 002 | 003 
A | AC  | IN  | AC 
B | AC  |  -  | -  
C | -   | AC  | -
```

Comment: The concept is cal'd `PIVOT`,which _RDBMS_ is this for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server PIVOT examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

Comment: can you teach me how to use PIVOT? I'm not really familar

Comment: is your value `001 | 002 | 003 ` is static or it changes

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Check my answer for static and dynamic pivots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, **static pivot**:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl (
    col1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    col2 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    col3 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES ('001', 'A', 'AC'),
       ('001', 'B', 'AC'),
       ('002', 'A', 'IN'),
       ('002', 'C', 'AC'),
       ('003', 'A', 'AC');


SELECT col2 as [ ], [001], [002], [003]
FROM 
    (
        SELECT col1, col2, col3 
        FROM tbl
    ) AS t1 
PIVOT 
(
    MAX(col3) 
    FOR col1 IN ([001], [002], [003]) 
) AS t2
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  | 001 | 002 | 003 
A | AC  | IN  | AC 
B | AC  |  -  | -  
C | -   | AC  | -
```

---

**EDIT**

Just now saw comments that you need **dynamic pivot**, here you go:

```
DECLARE @cols   AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @sql    AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols += QUOTENAME((col1)) + ','
                    FROM   (
                            SELECT  DISTINCT col1
                            FROM    tbl                         
                            ) a 

SET @cols   = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1)
SET @sql    = 'SELECT * 
               FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT col1, col2 as [ ], col3 
                        FROM tbl
                    ) x 
                    PIVOT
                    (
                        MAX (col3)
                        FOR col1 IN (' + @cols + ') 
                    ) p'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  | 001 | 002 | 003 
A | AC  | IN  | AC 
B | AC  |  -  | -  
C | -   | AC  | -
```