# Combine multiple rows into a single row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have a table like below :

```
    ID   TYPE    VALUE
    1    CC 1     X
    1    CC 2     Y
    1    CC 3    NULL
    1    CC 4    NULL
```

I am using sql PIVOT and STUFF functionality to get the desired result but still not able to do it. Please if anyone can help me.

Desired Result :

```
ID [CC 1]  [CC 2]  [CC 3]  [CC 4]
1    X       Y      NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Are the `type` values fix?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples

Comment: @juergend may be .. but these are in loop for a particular Id. Let say for Id 1 these are up to 13. then for 2 and so on.

Comment: I think you are confusing STUFF with XML concatinate methods. STUFF however doesn't work as you expect. All STUFF does is replace part of a varchar with another part, and when using contatinate is it normallly used to delete the first character

Answer (score 3):

You can approach this in several ways.  I typically use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when type = 'CC 1' then value end) as cc1,
       max(case when type = 'CC 2' then value end) as cc2,
       max(case when type = 'CC 3' then value end) as cc3,
       max(case when type = 'CC 4' then value end) as cc4
from <table t>
group by id;
```

Comment: Can we use stuff or pivot for this..  in other words i want the desired result using stuff or pivot. so please if u can help me..

Comment: @vivek . . . The reason I use conditional aggregation is because (1) it works in all databases and (2) it does produce unexpected results due to other columns in the table.  I have no idea why this query would require `stuff()`.

Answer (score 0):

`FULL OUTER JOIN`'s:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id, t3.id, t4.id),
       t1.value as cc1,
       t2.value as cc2,
       t3.value as cc3,
       t4.value as cc4
from (select id, value from tablename where type = 'CC 1') as t1
  full outer join (select id, value from tablename
                   where type = 'CC 2') as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  full outer join (select id, value from tablename
                   where type = 'CC 3') as t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
  full outer join (select id, value from tablename
                   where type = 'CC 4') as t  ON t3.id = t4.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Select id, listagg(value, '-')  within group(order by type) over (partition by id) as txt
From table group by Id, txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax for pivot;

```
SELECT ID, [CC 1],[CC 2],[CC 3],[CC 4]
FROM yourtable
PIVOT
(min([value])  
FOR Type
in([CC 1],[CC 2],[CC 3],[CC 4])  
)AS p
```