# T-SQL | SQL-Server Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the current query:

```
SELECT 
    cod.COM_DESC
   ,count(emp.OBE_Name) colValue
   ,'Total'[Desc] 
FROM OBP_EMP_MASTER emp
LEFT JOIN COMMONCODES cod 
  ON  emp.OBE_AGENT_DR = cod.COM_SLNO 
WHERE OBE_AGENT_DR IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY cod.COM_DESC

UNION ALL

SELECT 
     cod1.COM_DESC
    ,count(rep.OBE_Name) colValue
    ,'Replaced'[Desc]  
FROM OBP_EMP_REPLACE_HISTORY rep 
LEFT JOIN COMMONCODES cod1 
  ON rep.OBE_AGENT_DR = cod1.COM_SLNO 
WHERE OBE_AGENT_DR IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY cod1.COM_DESC
```

**RESULT**

[image]

**DESIRED RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Search for conditional sum or conditional aggregation.

Comment: You can also check for using `PIVOT` ;).

Comment: you have to show what have tried and why it failed. You cannot expect someone to post you entire solution and solve your problems

Comment: With that attitude, just go hire someone.

Comment: Although including sample data and results is a good start, please see [ask] for tips on improving your question to increase your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server PIVOT examples?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples)

Comment: Add more sample data, it's not quite clear how to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select
    Agent,
    max(case when `desc` = 'Total' then ColValue else 0 end) Total,
    max(case when `desc` = 'Replaced' then ColValue else 0 end) Replaced
from tbl
group by Agent
```

**Demo**  [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a92f5/4)

Comment: I suppose SUM is what OP wants. (Same answer with sample data, I know, but if OP adds more sample data we will know.)