# Get column field as rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table from those I need to get the column field as row

```
course          |orderedid  |name   |address    |phoneNumber
fairy           |1473       |john   |america    |   1234
tales           |1473       |john   |America    |   1234
Admin           |1473       |john   |america    |   1234
```

I need the result like the below:

```
course  course2    couse3   orderedid   name    address     phoneNumber
fairy   tales      Admin    1473        john    america     1234
```

How can I write this SQL query?

Comment: How many courses john may have?

Comment: thanks for reply @ Giorgi Nakeuri   here i have 12 courses

Comment: Exactly pivot is the solution :)

Comment: @Japongskie thanks for reply  sory to say i am very new to DB i am not understing pivot can you provide me any examples plz....

Comment: The sample you are looking is in the comment awhile ago, someone mark your question as duplicated of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-pivot-examples , the sample is already there.. if will take sometime here in stackoverflow and read the sample , you can understand to the pivot works.