# A list in the column header with ASP NET and Linq

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this structure
 [image]

and i want to get the following result
[image]

this means that i need to put the list of job in the header with  Linq / C# , can you guys help with it ?  i hope that my question is clear :)

Comment: The reality I'm afraid is that you need to show some effort / work you have done... that is why you are being marked down... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26657/Simple-LINQ-to-SQL-in-C

Comment: please show what you have done. then we can help

Comment: I need to know how can i do it in SQL , just put me in the right way, how can i put the list of job in the header ? is Group by , .... any function could help, i even don't know how can i look for it  in google :(

Comment: simple answer is you cant use it in sql. you have to write code to create this structure in a datatable

Answer (score 1):

Acually you're looking for `PIVOT` MS SQL function [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40625/1849444) for example.

You can do it without `PIVOT` like this:

```
SELECT 
   p.PersonName, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN j.IdJob IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) [IT],
   SUM(CASE WHEN j1.IdJob IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) [Teacher],
   SUM(CASE WHEN j2.IdJob IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) [Doctor]
FROM Person p
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Job j ON j.IdJob = p.IdJob AND j.JobName = 'IT'
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Job j1 ON j1.IdJob = p.IdJob AND j1.JobName = 'Teacher'
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Job j2 ON j2.IdJob = p.IdJob AND j2.JobName = 'Doctor'
GROUP BY p.PersonName
```

**Anyway there is no simple clear way to make `PIVOT` table without enumerating all column names.**