# How to pivot Text columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Our BA gave us Excel sheet with Two columns, `column1` and `column2` which I loaded in SQL Table. `column1` contains distinct Values `EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Address` and `column2` contains respected values.

How do I convert `Column1` distinct Values to Column so my table will have `EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, and Address` as columns?

```
File

Column1     || Column2
EmployeeID  || 00251
FirstName   || Joe
LastName    || Reed
Address     || 101 5th Ave
EmployeeID  || 00145
FirstName   || Jen
LastName    || Smith
Address     || 1001 Henderson RD
```

I am using the following query but it's giving an error.

```
  SELECT pt.EmployeeID , pt.FirstName, pt.LastName, pt.[Address]
  FROM 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM FlatFile.UserList

    ) AS temp
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX([COLUMN2])
            FOR [COLUMNE1] IN ('EmployeeID','FirstName','LastName:','[Address]')

        ) as pt
```

Error:

```
Error Message:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near 'EmployeeID'.
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you're keeping the error message a secret?

Comment: did u say columns in Excel sheet or in SQL database ?

Comment: Can u add sample source data and expected output aswel pls

Comment: @MatBailie: Sorry, I just attached error code.

Comment: @BHouse I received an excel file which I loaded it into SQL Table. Thank you ...

Comment: Typo?  `[COLUMNE1]` in the SQL and `COLUMN1` in the example data.

Comment: The list of fields shouldn't be strings.  Remove the `'`...  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Fix the typo `COLUMNE1` to `COLUMN1`, and remove the string quotes from the field list?

```
 SELECT pt.EmployeeID , pt.FirstName, pt.LastName, pt.[Address]
  FROM 
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM FlatFile.UserList

    ) AS temp
        PIVOT
        (
            MAX([COLUMN2])
            FOR [COLUMN1] IN ([EmployeeID],[FirstName],[LastName],[Address])
        ) as pt
```

[SQL Server: Examples of PIVOTing String data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470/sql-server-examples-of-pivoting-string-data)

Comment: Thank you !! It gave me only one value, I know I was using max but how should I get all values, the file has 3000 Employee Infomation.

Comment: You need to reformat your input data. Every row for the same employee needs a column that identifies it as being the same employee. So, for example, three columns : employee_id, column_name, data_value.  Best read the links I gave for  examples.